# Execute a command in Java without redirecting the output

Tags: java, exec, file-descriptor

How do I run an external command (via a shell) from a Java program, such that no redirection takes place, and wait for the command to end? I want the file descriptors of the external program to be the same as those of the Java program. In particular **I do not want the output to be redirected to a pipe that the Java program is reading**. Having the Java program relay the output is not a solution.

This means that a plain invocation of [`java.lang.Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) is not the solution. I presume that [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is involved, but how do I specify that output and error streams must be the same as the calling Java process?

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "foo");
            /*TODO: pb.out = System.out; pb.err = System.err;*/
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

(This may or may not be the right approach.)

In other words, **I'm looking for Java's `system`, but all I can find is (roughly) `popen`.**

Here's an example of a situation where relaying cannot work: if the subprocess writes to both stdout and stderr and the Java program is relaying, then the Java program has no way to know the order of the `write` calls in the subprocess. So the order of the output on stdout and stderr from the Java program will be observably different if the two streams end up in the same file. Mixing stdout and stderr is of course not a solution because the caller may want to keep them separate.

While I think this question is of general interest, a Linux-specific solution would solve my immediate problem.

Comment: You should use [`Process.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()). You need to read from both sysout and err for the process in two separate threads otherwise their buffers can fill up and the process will block. [This](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) is an excellent article on running external processes from Java. Personally I would use [Apache commons exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) to save yourself some pain.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't want to read the subprocess's output from the Java program.

Comment: If you don't want to relay the output, and you are content to stick to a platform specific solution, you might be able to use jni to call a wrapper which in turn calls the platform's native system() function.  However, remember that system() is blocking, so you may need to do this from its own thread.  It's possible you may run into various exec() related complications though, depending on how the JVM has things set up.  Another option would be to figure out what the current terminal is, and open that as stdout in the subprocess, maybe using an intermediary.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Terminal? Bogus assumption detected. Yes, JNI would be a solution, one that I'm reluctant to pursue due to the complexity. Not being a habitual Java programmer, I find it very odd that this language which has a very rich and complex library seemling doesn't have a solution for this simple task.

Comment: Then don't use a Terminal, but whatever the current output is - on linux you can find that from the links in /proc/self/fd if nothing else.  More fundamentally, there is a standard java solution to this, but you have rejected it out of your **mistaken belief** that the way you want to do things would behave differently.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No Java solution to do what I want has been proposed. I have rejected a way to do something different due to the **knowledge** that it doesn't do what I need. Your suggestion of having the command redirect to `/proc/$PPID/fd/1` should work, however — please write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intent of [`ProcessBuilder.redirectError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect))/[`redirectOutput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect)) which were introduced in Java 7. Using [`Redirect.INHERIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html#INHERIT) will make the child process share stderr/stdout with the Java process:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "foo");
            builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
            builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
            Process p = builder.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) project.  Disclaimer: I wrote it.  It provides non-blocking I/O from spawned processes.  You still have to relay in Java (you receive callbacks), but because it is using epoll() in the case of Linux, I would expect it to preserve the order of the underlying program.  Only a single thread is epoll()'ing the pipes so you won't get any thread scheduling order issues.

I'm 100% order would be preserved on MacOS X, or any BSD variant, because it uses a kqueue which is definitely ordered.  Anyway, you might want to give it a shot, it's trivial to code and test.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. By default all standard I/O of the child process are redirected to the parent process (the jvm running your java program).

[from the javadoc of the Process class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html):

> By default, the created subprocess does not have its own terminal or
>   console. **All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr)
>   operations will be redirected to the parent process, where they can be
>   accessed via the streams obtained using the methods getOutputStream(),
>   getInputStream(), and getErrorStream(). The parent process uses these
>   streams to feed input to and get output from the subprocess**. Because
>   some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard
>   input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream
>   or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess
>   to block, or even deadlock.

Comment: I know, by default they're redirecting. How do I change that?

Comment: Actually my bad. The point of interest in that javadoc, is `the created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console`. The use of "By default", is rather a poor choice of words in the javadoc. It simply means, that's the only way possible (as far as running in a terminal or console is concerned).

Comment: I don't want to create a terminal either — I'm not looking for `expect`. I want the output of the subprocess to go wherever the output of the Java process is going.

Comment: Something like merging both streams for instance?

Comment: Do you mean merging the subprocess's stdout with the Java process's stdout? That sounds like it should do what I want. (On the other hand, if it's merging the subprocess's stdout with the subprocess's stderr, I absolutely don't want that to happen.)

Comment: In that case, it's rather trivial. The output of the child process is piped through an input stream. All you would need is to read from that InputStream and write on the parent's OutputStream. It's manual but at least it's doable.

Comment: [Having the Java program relay the output is not a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366589/execute-a-command-in-java-without-redirecting-the-output). I'm really surprised that it would be this difficult — most languages give you `system` and don't always provide `popen`.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do it with java. Java is not meant for scripting. Groovy, (which is jvm-targeted language) however can do that rather easily:

`def cmd = "./longRunningProcess"

def process = cmd.execute()
process.waitForProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )`

Comment: @Gilles - of course having the Java program relay the output is a solution; it just may not be the solution **you prefer**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I refer you to the first paragraph of my question. It is a solution to some problems, but not mine. I want the subprocess's output (stdout and stderr) to be directly connected to the program that is listening to the Java program, without the Java program being a relay in between. A common problem that relaying doesn't solve is when the relay would mix up stdout and stderr out of order when they're on the same channel. And no, I can't merge them either, because then they'd end up merged even when I don't want them merged.

Comment: You are mistaken in your reason - two processes writing to the same file descriptor won't do so with nice synchronization either though they may sometimes *appear* to, if your programs only actually write(3) complete lines at a time.  In fact, by relaying you get *more* ability to prevent this, not less.  Also note that the system() function you proposed to use is blocking, so unless you are multithreaded you wouldn't be generating simultaneous message if mimicking that functionality anyway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Either you're misunderstanding how unix I/O works or you're misunderstanding my concern (I might not have phrased it clearly). If the subprocess writes (and I mean `write(2)`, I'm not talking about stdio buffering in this example) to stdout and stderr at “almost” the same time, the relaying Java program would have no way to know in which order to relay them. It's a common problem when you want to filter a stream but keep the order — it doesn't work reliably. See the tricks and caveats in [Stephane Chazelas's write-up on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12440), for example.

Comment: If you are talking about needing to preserve the order in which a single process writes to stdout and stderr, then you should have said so in your question - people can only answer the question you post.  So please use the edit function to fix that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My question already contains an equivalent requirement. (At least, it's equivalent on Linux and I believe other unices, maybe not on Windows.) I've added this as a motivating example. I did prominently mention in my question that relaying was not desired.